# Firebase Realtime Database Query Retrieve Records in Array - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database structure like below.
Users have some friends. For example, I am Joe and I'd like to fetch users who have friends as Joe.

In this example, Dave and Harry have a friend called Joe, so my query should fetch Dave and Harry but shouldn't Micheal.

Is there a way to do this without fetching data in a loop?

```
{
"Users": {
    "Joe": {
        "Friends": ["Dave","Harry","Micheal"]
    },
    "Dave": {
        "Friends": ["Joe","Jack","Brent"]
    },
    "Harry": {
        "Friends": ["Jack","Joe"]
    },
    "Micheal": {
        "Friends": ["Ken","Jack","Brent"]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you asking about Realtime Database or Firestore?

Comment: Realtime database

Answer (score 1):

`Firebase` Realtime database cannot perform a query across `array` members, to see if it contains a specific value in any position or to add/remove a record. `Firebase` documentation recommends against using arrays. One of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write.

As usual with NoSQL databases: if you can't perform the use-case you want with your current data structure, you can typically change/expand your data structure to allow the use-case. The best practice is to use `maps` instead of arrays. A possible database structure could look like this:

```
"Users": {
    "Joe": {
        "Friends"
            "Dave": true,
            "Harry": true,
            "Micheal": true
    },
    "Dave": {
        "Friends"
            "Joe": true,
            "Jack":true,
            "Brent": true

    },
    "Harry": {
        "Friends"
            "Jack": true,
            "Joe": true
    },
    "Micheal": {
        "Friends"
            "Ken":true,
            "Jack": true,
            "Brent": true
    }
}
```

You can also take a look, [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), for more informations.

Comment: Is there everything alright? Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Your answer Alex was usefull to me anyway.